# Mysql table with information on structure of another table

Tags: mysql, database

I want to make a table `A` with following fields: `id, name, type`.

which represents members in `B`
and a validation scheme for another table `B`

so let's say `A` have following data:

```
id  | Name | Type
0   | f1   | int
1   | f2   | date
```

then B have `f1` and `f2` as fields with the types `int` and `date`

my question, is that possible?

should I use it?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run this query:

```
DESCRIBE table_name;
```

it wil lgive you a list of column's names and types.

You would just need to find a way of automate the process to populate your table A

you can get a list of all table to loop through with:

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible since it's already done in the **INFORMATION_SCHEMA Tables**, the `COLUMNS` table would provide you with the member details of any table.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html